# NodeJs Populate Mongoose data with custom propertied instead of _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Schema's first one is Users and second one is Wallets Schema each user has property of walletDetails inside user schema which holds the type of ObjectId of Wallet which is associated with the user.

User Schema

```
import { model, Schema, Document, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { IUser } from '@interfaces/users.interface';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { ResponseFlags } from '@enums/response/response.flags';

const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

const userAccountStatus: Array<String> = ['ACTIVE', 'BLOCKED', 'NONACTIVE'];

const userSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true,
      unique: true,
      required: ResponseFlags.INVALID_EMAIL,
    },
    userId: {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      unique: true,
      required: false,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      minlength: 4,
      required: true,
    },

    lastName: {
      type: String,
      minlength: 3,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      minlength: 12,
      maxlength: 100,
      required: ResponseFlags.INVALID_PASSWORD,
    },
    walletDetails: {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'Wallet',
    },
    
    accountStatus: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      enum: userAccountStatus,
      default: 'NONACTIVE',
    },
    role: {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Permission',
      required: false,
    },
  },

  { timestamps: true },
);

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword: string, callback: any) {
  // @ts-ignore
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, (err: Error, isMatch: boolean) => {
    callback(err, isMatch);
  });
};

userSchema.methods.genrateToken = function (callback: any) {
  // @ts-ignore
  return jwt.sign({ email: this.email }, JWT_SECRET);
};

const userModel = model<IUser & Document>('User', userSchema);
export default userModel;
```

Here is the Wallet Schema

```
import { IWallet } from '@interfaces/wallet/wallet.interface';
import { model, Schema, Document, Types } from 'mongoose';
import mongooseUniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';

const walletSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    walletId: {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      unique: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      index: true,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    currentBalance: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: new Date(),
    },
    currency: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'PENCE',
    },
    totalSpend: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    deposits: [
      {
        type: Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Deposit'
      }
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);



walletSchema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);
const walletModel = model<IWallet & Document>('Wallet', walletSchema);
export default walletModel;
```

WalletDetails inside User schema contains the id of wallet which is exact same as walletId inside WalletSchema.

I just want that when i userModel.populate("WalletDetails") it should return the same object as id from Wallet. i have heared of virtual populations but i'm not able to make it.

Comment: Can you add an example to your problem statement? 
Its a bit difficult to understand what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual leave your schema as it is.

```
userSchema.virtual('wallet', {
  ref: 'Wallet',
  localField: 'walletDetails',
  foreignField: 'walletId',
  justOne: true
});
```

foreign field must exist inside the child schema and local field.